# i need to get scan a input of (octal or hexadecimal) for this what specificer should i use in common to hexadecimal and octal

Tags: c, type-conversion, octal

Am I able to get input of octal or hexadesimal number by using a common specifer for both in c program
Or what should do to know the input type

Comment: Use `%i`. It will recognize `0x` prefix for hex and `0` prefix for octal.

Answer (score 0):

Writing up @Barmar's suggestion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int i;
        scanf("%i", &i);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        return 0;
}
```

and example run with octal and hex input::

```
010
8
```

```
0x10
16
```